# Use SVG in CompoundDrawable with SDK<21

Tags: android, svg, textview

I was using SVG's in my Android application as `src` of my ImageView, using `appSrc` attribute in order to give compatibility backwards (SDK<21).
But now I have tried to use them in my TextView Compound Drawables (drawableXXX attributes) and I get multiple errors when I use a device with KitKat (The same errores that I had when I used `android:src` instead of `app:srcCompat`).

> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #261: Error inflating class

Is there anyone who know a way to use them in Compound Drawables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as of now you cannot add a VectorDrawable from xml attributes, that functionality is only limited to `app:srcCompat` more on this in the android developers [blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html)

However you may do it programmatically using `VectorDrawableCompat.create(Resources, int, Theme)` and then add it as a compound drawable to the TextView using `TextView#setCompoundDrawables`

see : 
 
developer.android.com/reference/android/support/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawableCompat.html
developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html

Comment: Great, It is what I was searching for. In my case I had to use `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds` instead of `setCompoundDrawables` because this one didn't show the SVG.
Thank you very much for your help, It was really useful!

Comment: Using `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds` worked for me too.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and i found only two options:

1) set your drawable programmatically or create a custom view

2) remove "vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true" from your build.gradle

> This will cause Android Studio to generate PNGs at compile time for apps with a minSdkVersion less than API 21 while using your vectors on API 21+ devices, allowing you to keep the same code at the cost of additional APK size.

Comment: As I told to Sachkham, the first option is what I needed. Thank your for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

As is described in [this article](https://mobikul.com/creating-textviews-drawable-supporting-vector-images/), you can create a little hack for this issue. Just create `layer-list` drawable file(ic_working_image.xml) like this:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_your_image_name"/>
</layer-list>
```

And then just use the new drawable on TextView as before with drawableXXX attributes.